# What happens if define a class without __init__ method?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

Suppose that I have defined four classes as following:

(The code has been **tested on Python 3.6.5**. However, I expected it **should also works on Python 2.7.x** with `from __future__ import print_function`)

```
In [1]: class A(object):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
   ...: class B(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, value):
   ...:         print('B(value=%s)' % value)
   ...: 
   ...: class C(A):
   ...:     def __init__(self, value):
   ...:         print('C(value=%s)' % value)
   ...:         super(C, self).__init__(value)
   ...: 
   ...: class D(A, B):
   ...:     def __init__(self, value):
   ...:         print('D(value=%s)' % value)
   ...:         super(D, self).__init__(value)
   ...:         

In [2]: C.mro()
Out[2]: [__main__.C, __main__.A, object]

In [3]: D.mro()
Out[3]: [__main__.D, __main__.A, __main__.B, object]
```

Note two things:

1. `class A` without `__init__` method;
2. Both C and D have the same successor `A` according the mro
   information.

So I suppose that both `super(C, self).__init__(value)` and `super(D, self).__init__(value)` will trigger the `__init__` method defined in `A`.

However, the following result confused me very much!

```
In [4]: C(0)
C(value=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-75d9b7f7d447> in <module>()
----> 1 C(0)

<ipython-input-1-5252938615c6> in __init__(self, value)
      9     def __init__(self, value):
     10         print('C(value=%s)' % value)
---> 11         super(C, self).__init__(value)
     12 
     13 class D(A, B):

TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters

In [5]: D(1)
D(value=1)
B(value=1)
Out[5]: <__main__.D at 0x2a6e8755b70
```

We can see that `class D` have initialization succeed, while `class C` failed.

What make the different behavior between `class C` and `class D`?

**EDIT** I don't think my question is about the mro (actually I known the mro about python more or less), my question is about the different behavior of `__init___` method.

**EDIT2** I'm silly, it's about mro.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: For D it work because when super can't find init in parent class A it try to look for init in class B where init exist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Class `A` has no separate `__init__` method - it is looked up via `A` `s own `mro`.

   ```
   >>> A.__init__ is object.__init__
   True
   ```
2. Class B has a separate `__init__` method - it does not require traversing the `mro`.

   ```
   >>> B.__init__ is object.__init__
   False
   ```

Note that the difference is *having* and *inheriting* `__init__`. Just because `A.__init__` can be provided does not mean `A` has an `__init__` method by itself.

1. When C looks up its `super().__init__`, the following is tried:

   - `C.__init__` is skipped
   - `A.__init__` does not exist
   - `object.__init__` exists and is called
2. When D looks up its `super().__init__`, the following is tried:

   - `D.__init__` is skipped
   - `A.__init__` does not exist
   - `B.__init__` exists and is called
   - `object.__init__` is never looked up

This difference is a major point to using `super` instead of an explicit base class. It allows inserting specialised classes into a hierarchy ([example](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)).

Comment: `C.__init__` does not exist? Looks like it was defined.

Comment: @QiangXu Thanks for pointing this out. I have adjusted the answer accordingly.

Comment: `super(C, self).__init__` was called from inside `C__init__`, right? If that is the case, then `C.__init__` was not skipped, was it? Please correct me if I am wrong on this.

Comment: @QiangXu It is skipped *in the lookup of* C's ``super().__init__``. ``super`` starts its search in the mro *after* the current method's class.

Comment: `super(C, self).__init__` was invoked by `C.__init__`, wasn't it? I am a bit confused...

Comment: @QiangXu Yes, ``C.__init__`` invokes ``super(C, self).__init__``. But when ``super(C, self).__init__`` looks for ``__init__`` in the mro, it skips ``C.__init__``. Otherwise, ``C.__init__`` would keep calling itself infinitely.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this behavior is the way attribute lookup works in python. When you access `A.__init__`, python internally traverses `A`'s MRO until it finds a class that *defines* an `__init__` attribute. **Inherited attributes are disregarded during this lookup.**

When you call `super(C, self).__init__(value)` in `C.__init__`, python traverses the MRO `[A, object]` until it finds an `__init__` attribute. The important thing is that `A` does *not* define an `__init__` attribute, so the lookup goes past `A` to `object` and returns `object.__init__`.

The same thing happens in `D.__init__`, except in this case the MRO being traversed is `[A, B, object]`. Again, `A` doesn't define an `__init__`, so the lookup continues and returns `B.__init__`.

---

As an experiment, you can change the definition of `A` to define an `__init__` like so:

```
class A(object):
    __init__ = object.__init__
```

And you'll notice that instantiating `D` now throws the same error as `C`:

```
>>> D(3)
D(value=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "untitled.py", line 17, in __init__
    super(D, self).__init__(value)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```